# Wordpress: Deleting Custom Post Type from custom table

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have created a custom post and on save/update, it adds the data to a custom table.

On delete, the data remains in the custom table, but is removed from the wp_posts table, so it SEEMS like it is deleted.

To keep my tables slim and usable, I don't want to bog them down with dead data.

Is there any way to say "on custom post delete, delete from custom table as well"? Searched the WP Codex and stackoverflow, both came up empty. There has to be a way, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define [add_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) for [delete_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_post) that removes the data.
Something like this:

```
add_action( 'delete_post', 'my_custom_table_delete', 10 );
function my_custom_table_delete( $post_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT post_id FROM my_custom_table WHERE post_id = %d', $post_id ) ) ) {
        return $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 'DELETE FROM my_custom_table WHERE post_id = %d', $post_id ) );
    }
    return true;
}
```